# Update Old Angular codebase to latest (v15)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am looking for the least painful way to update an angular application from v7 to v15.
I have started out on it, its a pretty large codebase with loads of packages and implementations that are deprecated. Is there an easier way to go about this?
Thank you for your answers!

I used

```
ng update @angular/cli
```

also did for the core angular modules. Its just really a lot and I wanted to find out if there was an easier way around it.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of updateing such big steps is by made it to little simpler steps one by one.

I always use the angular update guide to get all the recommended and needed changes: https://update.angular.io/

If you use this guide and update major version by major version it should be easier to you.

Answer (score 1):

I recently updated our Angular application (relatively simple one) from:
v11 to v12 with no real issues, then
v12 to v13 with no real issues, then
v13 to v14. The only pitfall was the new introduced Cypress e2e test tool.

Currently, I'm working on v14 to v15, which is a huge changer because most of the material components have been changed to the new "Standalone" architecture (not sure how to call it).
The first part went well, following the [Update guide](https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=14.0-15.0).
I had only some problems with ESLinter TypeScript problems. Reporting a lot of implicit `any` definitions.

But this update did only Angular, and still uses the legacy code of Angular v14 material components. In the [Migration guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration) there is an instruction to update also the material components.

This last step, updating material components, broke my complete application. I couldn't build anymore, unit test failing, styling problems, and Cypress test failing.
Reason: module code imports where gone, `@NgModule()` affected. Cypress complaining that input fields are blocked from view ...

I can say, v15 is a hard one, in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just do a fresh installation of an angular app. After that, go on and migrate the modules that you have into the new one. Its tricky, you might have to be mindful of the packages though